# "Data Undefined" in Meteor

Tags: jquery, meteor

I keep returning a "Cannot read property 'data' of undefined" error when I hit submit:

```
Template.postItem.rendered = function() { 
  $(document).on('click', '#mysubmit', function(e, template) {
    e.preventDefault();  
    var inputval = $("#myinput").val(); 
    var time = {
      begins: inputval,
      postId: template.data._id
   };

    time._id = Times.insert(time);
 });
}
```

Shouldn't Meteor be receiving the "template.data._id" from the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meteor provides event maps on templates which you can use to pass in 'event' and 'template' in order to access the data context. You shouldn't need to respond to a click event from the rendered() function using jquery unless you are doing something out of the ordinary.

You can rewrite your event like this to access the 'template' data:

```
Template.postItem.events({
  "click #myinput": function(event, template){
    event.preventDefault();
    var postId = template.data._id; // template.data is now accessible
    // etc.
  }
});
```

UPDATE:

If you still need to access your template data through the `rendered()` function, you can access it through `Template.instance().data`:

```
Template.postItem.rendered = function(){
  var data = Template.instance().data;
  $(document).on('click', '#mysubmit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  
    var inputval = $("#myinput").val(); 
    var time = {
      begins: inputval,
      postId: data._id
   };
   time._id = Times.insert(time);
}
```

Comment: I suppose I am doing something out of the ordinary. The form is inside a bootstrap popover, which requires the jQuery on() to bind the event.  Do you know of a way to use on() inside Template.name.events?

Comment: No problem, I updated my answer with an example (which I have not checked but should point you in the right direction)